# Question about lemma in Dirichlet problem in a strip (conformal mappings) Stein and Shakarchi

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this from Stein and Shakarchi:
[image: page1]

I don't understand the statement that $u \circ F$ is harmonic because H is holomorphic? How is it harmonic i.e. $\triangle (u \circ F) = 0$?

Comment: The real part (and the imaginary part) of a holomorphic function is harmonic. You can prove that (for example) with the Cauchy-Riemann equations for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901977/how-to-show-the-real-part-of-a-holomorphic-function-is-harmonic.