# For a real number $r$, if $u(x,y)=x^3 − rxy^2 + 12xy − 12x$ is the real part of a holomorphic function, prove that $r = 3$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> For a real number $r$, let $ u(x, y) = x^3 − rxy^2 + 12xy − 12x$.
> Prove that if $u(x, y)$ is the real part of a holomorphic function, then $r = 3$.

What I've tried:

I know that: $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$,
where $z = x + i y$

Find partial derivatives with respect to x and y:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 3x^2 - ry^2 + 12y - 12$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -2rxy + 12x$

Now I'm stuck. Am I on the right track? What is next move?

Comment: Definition of a harmonic function: $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial y^{2}}=0$

Comment: The real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1901977/how-to-show-the-real-part-of-a-holomorphic-function-is-harmonic) for a proof.

Comment: Ok, so i can equate them with the Cauchy-Riemann equations? And set them equal to eachother to get zero.. is that the way? I don't understand the role of r = 3 plays.

Comment: You can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that $u$ is harmonic, i.e. $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$. See my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations other than to prove that the given function is harmonic, that is
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0
$$
that becomes
$$
6x-2rx=0
$$
and therefore $r=3$.

Note that the condition is also sufficient, because the function is polynomial. With the C-R equations you can find the imaginary part (the conjugate harmonic function). You need
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} &= 3x^2 - 3y^2 + 12y - 12 \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} &= 6xy -12x
\end{align}
Integrating the latter with respect to $x$ we see that
$$
v(x,y)=3x^2y-6x^2+\varphi(y)
$$
and differentiating with respect to $y$ we get
$$
3x^2+\varphi'(y)=3x^2 - 3y^2 + 12y - 12
$$
so, up to an additive constant,
$$
\varphi(y)=-y^3+6y^2-12y
$$
and you have
$$
u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=x^3 − 3xy^2 + 12xy − 12x + i(3x^2y-6x^2-y^3+6y^2-12y)
$$
Now you see that, with $z=x+iy$,

- $x^3+3ix^2y-3xy^2-iy^3=z^3$
- $-6ix^2+12xy+6iy^2=-6i(x^2+2ixy-y^2)=-6iz^2$
- $-12x-12iy=-12z$

so your function is (up to an imaginary constant)
$$
f(z)=z^3-6iz^2-12z
$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations for this:
$$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy}$$ and $$\frac{du}{dy} = -\frac{dv}{dx}$$

If we differentiate the first equality again with respect to x, we get:
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{dv}{dy} = \frac{d}{dy}\frac{dv}{dx} = -\frac{d^2u}{dy^2}$$
Here, we switched the order of differentiation, which is allowed as v(x,y) is part of a holomorphic function.
Now, this gives Laplace's Equation: $\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2u}{dy^2} = 0$

Now, starting from the first derivatives of the original post, we find the following second derivatives:
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} = 6x$$
$$\frac{d^2u}{dy^2} = -2rx$$
Substituting in Laplace's Equation then results in:
$$ 6x - 2rx = 0 $$
$$r = 3$$